# Округление числа до ближайшего меньшего из ряда

Tags: c#, округление

Есть массив `{ 2.4, 4, 7.6 }` и число `2.5`. Оно должно округлиться до `2.4` (ближайшее меньшее). Есть ли встроенные методы для такого округления? Если нет, то как можно такое реализовать самому?

Comment: самому такое можно реализовать в цикле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double n = 2.5;
double[] array = { 2.4, 4, 7.6 };
double result = array.Where(x => x <= n).Max();
```

Comment: "до ближайшего меньшего"

Comment: Ааа, исправил. Это даже проще